# Push notification for content resolver from content provider

Tags: android, communication, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, inter-process-communicat

I want to know if there is a way to inform content resolver/s if the content provider change data.

In my case there is an app that shows data base content. There is another app, that modifies data in db. Now I want to know if it's possible to notify the app via push that data has changed in background.

I do not found any information about content resolver connecting to content provider. 
Also I know no way to communicate between content provider and resolver the wrong way.

Do anybody now if its possible or has a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a [`ContentObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html)?

Comment: For those who try the same like me. See: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/observing-content.html